# How do I remove a control from a group?

Tags: livecode

So, I have a setup script that runs every time I open the program. I have 10 or so different fld variables that I want to add or remove from a group based on whether the number at the end of their id is less than or equal to the length of a randomly generated word, in this case known as the variable `randomword`. In case the letters are not in the group and therefore cannot be removed, I want to only try to remove it but if unsuccessful just move on to the next value of `x`. I know how to add something to a group, but not remove a single control from that group. How can I run a script so that:

```
for x = 1 to 10
    put length(randomword) into tLen
    if x <= tLen
        copy fld ("letter"&x) to group "letters"
    else
        try:
        remove fld ("letter"&x) from group "letters"
    end if
end for
```

Everything below the `else` statement above is pseudocode as I don't actually know how to do that. Anyone with a working solution to this would make my day.

Comment: Please, study the user manual PDF (included with LiveCode) or a book such as LiveCode Mobile Development Beginner's Guide (by Colin Holgate) or Programming LiveCode for the Real Beginner (by me) or check the LiveCode website for lots of introductory materials. This will help you to get familiar with the basics and to develop your software much more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a control from a group, use the delete command:

```
delete fld ("letter" & x) of group "letters"
```